# Validity of 90-day tourist Schengen visa after Blue Card or resident permit expiration

Tags: germany, resident-permit, blue-card, schengen

I am wondering about the following scenario:

- I am the holder of a Residence Permit (Blue Card or other) in a Schengen country (e.g: Germany)
- My passport normally allows me to stay up to 90 days in a 180-day period insidey the Schengen area (as tourist)

Let's say I decide to leave Germany permanently (unregistering), meaning that my residence permit would be invalidated (assuming this has immediate effect?).

My question is: how long could I travel inside the Schengen area as a tourist after losing my residence permit? Would this mean that I would have 90 days, provided that the rest of my stay in the Schengen area was thanks to my permit?

How would this be enforced?

Can I prove I once was a residence permit holder and my 90 days didn't count during that period?

Comment: It is not really enforced, but the residence permit card togeather with the date of the deregistertion will serve as the entry date stamp replacement. Once the Entry/Exit system comes into to force, the  deregistertion date should be entered into the system.

Answer (score 2):

> Would this mean that I would have 90 days, provided that the rest of my stay in the Schengen area was thanks to my permit?

Yes.  The [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02016R0399-20190611) provides that periods of stay authorized under a D visa or a residence permit do not count towards the 90-day limit.  Article 6(2):

> For the purposes of implementing paragraph 1, the date of entry shall be considered as the first day of stay on the territory of the Member States and the date of exit shall be considered as the last day of stay on the territory of the Member States. Periods of stay authorised under a residence permit or a long-stay visa shall not be taken into account in the calculation of the duration of stay on the territory of the Member States.

> How would this be enforced?

When you leave, they'll look for your entrance stamp.  You can show your residence permit at that point, which might be the end of the matter, but if it isn't you can show that your deregistration was less than 90 days earlier.

> Can I prove I once was a residence permit holder and my 90 days didn't count during that period?

Exactly that, yes.